# Monitor variables of a running program?

Tags: java, monitoring

I'm working on a small multiplayer game which has a tick method which does all kind of logic things like moving, creating and checking game elements.

The tick method is called every 100 milliseconds. Sometimes things go wrong due a bug. But these bugs are hard to track down mainly because things are being called many times a second. So when i add a debug log entry at some points the log gets overcrowded and not really easy to understand.

Is there a way to monitor certain variables while the game keeps running?

I tried jmx but the time to setup jmx to monitor a variable is quite long due the complex nature of jmx. In addition when tracking a but i don't know which variable to monitor, this means i need to switch from variable to variable quickly.

Comment: Other then logging to an output file no there is not. Unless you remote debug the application in which point you have to step through the code.

Comment: You can debug your program and watch variables' values change too with most usable IDEs.

Comment: If you mean to monitor the values of your variables at runtime, I don't think there's such option unless the application is run in debug mode.

Comment: @TinusTate which langauge / environment are you using ?

Comment: @Abhishrek java is currently being used, note the java tag ;-)

Comment: @Mena while in debug mode (in eclipse) you have to stop the program and use debug controls to step through the lines of code. But when you run a program the variables are not visible.

Comment: @TinusTate maybe filter the debug output ? Dump it to a file ?

Comment: @Abhishrek a log entry that is filtered might lead to the cause of the bug, so to search for the bug almost all log entries (that are added to find the bug) may be important. I was hoping there was a program that monitored variables or maybe less preferable a program where i could push variable values to and that they would be displayed in a easy to read way. Of course i could make one but i don't like reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a big problem with Game design where draws are called 30/60 times a second.

I found that outputting all the values on screen helped a lot as it doesn't save the previous values so you can easily see when things change.

You also can add breakpoints when a value is changes to a range it shouldn't be, thus allowing you to inspect the code further such as

```
  1 if(val>1000){
  2     debugger;
  3 }
```

Comment: The hint about outputting the values on screen was a really nice one. I quickly wrote a jframe with a jtable where code can put variable values. The jtable refreshes every few seconds, resulting in a table that displays my variables while the program runs. With 1 line of code i update a variable in the table. Simple things are nice!

Comment: Great my advise helped :) Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

I think that [Chronon DVR for Java](http://chrononsystems.com) or a similar tool could be a solution for you, you could record everything and then analyse afterwards trying to spot the bug causing the issue .

> Chronon records the entire execution of your Java program and saves it
>   to disk. Recordings can be played back any time, thus eliminating
>   those 'Non Reproducible' bugs.

Alternatively you could try to attach the Eclipse debugger to a remote running Java application, take a look at [this guide](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-eclipse-javadebug/index.html) for more information.

Comment: That is one interesting piece of software, i watched the first video and is has a lot of features for finding/tracing problems a long time after it happened. I'll need to research it a bit more to find out if it is useful for my kind of bugs.